# Extracting subtree for a TreeForm

Tags: expression-manipulation, trees

How can I extract an entire subtree from a `TreeForm` starting from a specific point of the tree?
Because with `Extract` or `Part` you can take only that specific point...

Comment: Can you help potential helpers by giving an example of what you're expecting to see?

Comment: Have you looked at `Level`?

Answer (score 3):

@N.J.Evans is right. Choosing second branch at the level 3:

[image]

Code:

```
exp = Integrate[(1 + x^1)/(1 - x^3), x]
TreeForm[exp]
Level[exp, {3}][[2]] // TreeForm
Level[exp, {3}]
```

Answer (score 3):

### `` SparseArray`ExpressionToTree ``

Using @Vitaly's example

```
exp = Integrate[(1 + x^1)/(1 - x^3), x];
```

construct edges and `Tooltip`ped vertices from `` SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[exp] ``

```
rules = List @@@ SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[exp];
edges = DirectedEdge @@@ (rules[[All, All, 2]] + 1); 
vertices = Property[#2 + 1, 
 {VertexLabels -> Dynamic@Tooltip[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
    Column[{Style[#1, 16], #3}, Alignment -> Center], 
    Style[#1, 16]], #2 + 1]}] & @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[rules, 1]];
```

and use them with `TreeGraph`

```
tg = TreeGraph[vertices, edges, ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 600, 
   VertexSize -> Medium];
```

Use `VertexDelete[tg, Range[n]]` to delete the first `n` vertices:

```
Row[{tg, SetProperty[VertexDelete[tg, Range[11]],
    {VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[tg][[12 ;;]], ImageSize -> 400}]}]
```

[image]